# Ломается меню, что я делаю не так?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
body {
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
/*END GENERAL STYLES*/

/*MAIN MENU*/
.main-menu {
 padding: 40px 180px 40px 180px;
}
.logo {
 display: inline-block;
}
.logo h2 {
 float: left;
}
.menu {
 float: right;
}

.menu li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 8px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <title>Company Name</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <header class="main-menu">
   <div class="logo">
    <h2>Company Name</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </header>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: я так понимаю это из за width: 100%

Comment: А как должно быть, если ширины не хватает?

Comment: окей, тогда в силу должен вступать медиа запрос?)

Comment: Ну, сложно посоветовать какое-то решение, если неизвестно, какого эффекта нужно добиться. Так-то текущий вариант, как по мне, отлично подходит. :)

Comment: @SurfinBird понял), скорее это уже нужно смотреть уроки по адаптивности мне:)